# Importance of diversity statement in graduate application

Tags: phd, application

I am applying for a PhD in engineering and some universities require a diversity statements which is considered an optional part of the application.

How important is this to the admission ? They don't say how they are going to use this in their admissions process and I believe the department makes the decisions.

Should I spend the time to do this or just forget about it since it is optional ?